# Wordpress template path hints like Magento

Tags: wordpress

In Magento there is an option to show each path from a template file that is loaded on the current page.

Is there something for Wordpress, I need to change parts of a page were a search thing is loaded but I can't find in which file it is...

Regards,
Robert

Answer (score 1):

This plugin will help you out:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-template-hints/#description

You just need to activate it and it will show you template hints like Magento, and if you want to remove template hint, just deactivate plugin